# Re-attach roof rack rails

Tags: body

I put a table on the roof of my 2000 Subaru Forester. I was a little too enthusiastic tightening the ratchets on the tie-down straps and the front of the rail which attaches to the roof pulled up.

Any recommendations on how to fix it? Glue? Sealant? Clips?

Pictures [here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/j7pAzMAYB1GKBJXs2).

Thanks :-)

Comment: Is it the plastic cover? Or have you deformed the roof? The plastic cover may just push back down. The roof....

Comment: Yes, post pictures of the area.

Comment: Pictures added. I don't think that I've actually bent metal. I'm wondering if I've snapped some clips under there. Sorry that the pictures aren't clearer :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be clips, rivits or screws. I would recommend removing the rack if it is easy to do, then look at what is bent? Roof, rack or both. If the roof is bent then MAYBE you could tap it back down gently and re-install the rack.  Or if the rack is bent you could try the same thing using something solid under the rack and tap it back down.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my original comment "Is it the plastic cover? Or have you deformed the roof? The plastic cover may just push back down. The roof.... ".

Take the rack off and see if you are lucky with the fixing points.

They are designed to take 50 to 75kg load so may be ok.

Another possibility is that the bars themselves have deformed a bit which has caused the leading edge to lift - in which case you may find replacing them may be the easiest. Second-hand may be an option.